# Automatically create new page for a new post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have converted html static page into wordpress theme and made simple blog page.
I would like to have 3 posts per single page.

Can somebody tell me how to automaticaly create a new page after 3 posts and to navigate through pages and their posts?

Comment: I think your understanding of WordPress page templates and posts is incorrect. In WordPress it isn't necessary to create a new page template as new posts are added. The page template is reused but is instantiated using a different set of posts.

Comment: I think you need to set Publish immediately(Future Publish date) in Publish section. So that with the date the post automatically displayed in your site.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the php code with div id="wp-content" , i tried to add some style, width, background color and it works.

However i have very limited control with styling these posts.

I can style wp-content div or #wp content img or p{ (div which is pointing to the paragraphs or images).

I would like to style my posts separately, for example to add different width for first image and paragraph, and the other for the last two and different layout too.

When i go on "inspect element" - all the images have allignnone class, h3 and p tags dont have anything.

How to differently style paragraphs, images and headings to the 3 latest post?

```html
<?php
$number_of_posts = 3;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => $number_of_posts );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent_post ){
echo "<span>".$recent_post['post_date']."</span> <br>";
echo "<h3>".$recent_post['post_title']."</h3>";
echo  "<p>".$recent_post['post_content']."</p><br><br>";
 }

 ?>
</div>
```